# Running PowerShell script from batch file as SYSTEM

Tags: powershell

There are various posts I have seen showing how to run a PowerShell script from a batch file, however I am still not quite sure how to do this with admin rights or running under the system account. I have a batch file that needs to execute a PowerShell script and run the script as admin or the local system account WITHOUT prompting for credentials. This is running on end user machines that do not have the permissions. This is the best I have found for executing a powershell script from a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
PAUSE
```

But UAC will prompt with the above. Any ideas?

Comment: why not using task scheduler?

Comment: @cb - could be an interactive script.

Comment: @kev if so user can interact with UAC :)

Comment: Run it as a scheduled task as SYSTEM or LOCAL SERVICE with the "run with highest privileges" setting enabled. This is a question for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) rather than SO.

Comment: Task scheduler may be an option, but we have a mechanism where we can run batch files after a VPN connection is established. It would be nice to have the powershell script run right when the user connects to VPN instead of having it pushed via group policy after the VPN connection is established. So what you are saying is it is not possible to execute a powershell script as an admin or system account from a batch file without prompting for the user's credentials?

Comment: -Verb RunAs in your command explicitly opens authentication prompt to elevate privileges in UAC. Try this. Download psexec from Microsoft and run batch file as PSEXEC -i -s -d "path_to_batchfile.bat" and remove "-Verb RunAs" from your batch file.